# "You need to supply at least one validation" but Rails validation exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the following validation:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :starts, :ends

  validates :no_multi_day_events

  private
    def no_multi_day_events
      if (ends.day != starts.day)
        errors.add(:ends, "No multi-day events")
      end
    end
end
```

However, when I try to load a page with this text, I get an error: `You need to supply at least one validation`

How do I supply the validation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be calling:

```
validate :no_multi_day_events
```

and not

```
validates :no_multi_day_events
```

Comment: OMG.... my eye has something wrong.. you did save me. thanks you... i think everyone who searched this answer with googling are need get some fresh air and cup of coffee.